# join few columns with importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, concatenation

I wish to join few columns in a importrange,

i am using this formula here
**=importrange("URL", "A1:J3")** "i would like to join A, D, H here"**; importrange("URL", "L1:Z3")** "and to join M, P here"

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to concatenate row by row those columns of the imported ranges?

Something like this?? Used INDEX to refer to the columns in each row. If needed you can change CONCATENATE with JOIN or TEXTJOIN to add some separator:

```
=BYROW(IMPORTRANGE(URL,"A1:J3"),LAMBDA(each, CONCATENATE(INDEX(each,,1),INDEX(each,,4),INDEX(each,,8))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can use the QUERY function to join specific columns from multiple IMPORTRANGE functions as I previously described.

I have added the code of joining A, D, H from the first IMPORTRANGE function, and columns M, P from the second IMPORTRANGE function:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL", "A1:J3"), IMPORTRANGE("URL", "L1:Z3")}, "SELECT Col1, Col4, Col8, Col13, Col16")
```

Comment: what i want is the first part of this importrange to merge there itself while import seperately

=importrange("URL", "A1:J3") "i would like to join / concatenate A, D, H here" different from the second range